# Powershell Base64 URL-safe encode the binary hash string above to make it suitable for HTTP requests

Tags: string, powershell, hash, binary, base64url

I want to Base64 URL-safe encode my "binary hash string" value that comes as input from my previous code line to make it suitable for HTTP requests, i.e. final_hash = base64_url_safe_encode(binary_hash_str). Where i can use the final hashed password for authentication purpose in powershell.
I was not able to find any code in powershell.

Comment: "for authentication purpose" - do you intend to pass it as part of a header (eg. for Basic authentication, `Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46...`), or as a query parameter in the URL (eg. `https://domain.tld/some/path?key=YWRtaW46...`)?

Comment: Hashed password will be sent here: $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$body = "{
username: user, 
password: hashed_password }"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://192.158.10.21/api/token' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response

Comment: When the server receives the hashed password it will send me a token which i will be passing as a header ("Authorization", "Bearer access token")

Answer (score 2):

Converting a byte array to base64 in PowerShell can be done with [`[Convert]::ToBase64String()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string):

```
$binString = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Secret string")
$base64String = [Convert]::ToBase64String($binString)
```

If you want to use the resulting base64 string as part of the request payload (eg. a header or part of the request body), you can go ahead and use it as is:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Header @{ Authorization = "Basic ${base64String}"}
```

If you need to pass it as a query parameter in the url itself, escape it with `[uri]::EscapeDataString()`:

```
$URI = 'https://domain.tld/path?param={0}' -f [uri]::EscapeDataString($base64String)
Invoke-WebRequest $URI
```

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try